# jsf web.xml to java config

Tags: config, web.xml

I wonder what is the equivalent of the following code ( web.xml) in Java.
.........................................................................

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Welcome page -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- JSF mapping -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

And xml([extensible markup language](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_whatis.asp)) file is just a way to store and transport data. There is no equivalent java class nor instance.

To learn more about how this data is used check: [java servlets](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/web-xml.html)